# Where do I store a build artifact in Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a simple pipeline in my Azure DevOps which uses a private agent on my application server. Therefor I can just copy the build artifact to the correct directory when I want to deploy the application.

The pipeline has three steps:

1. build
2. deploy to staging
3. deploy to prod

The second step is always performed directly after the build process. However the third step (deploy to prod) is executed some days afterward as there is an approval needed for this stage.

**My question: is it fine if I leave the build artefact from the first step somewhere in the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)-directory?**

Actually it is working right now. But I am a bit afraid that some day I will get a mess when e.g. the next pipeline run is triggered before the last was finished or my private agent gets a new job from another task.

This is my simplified yaml:

```
stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build_Frontend
        displayName: Build-Frontend
        pool:
          name: $(poolName)
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '14.x'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'
          - script: |
              npm install
            displayName: 'npm install'
            workingDirectory: "smprod/"
          - script: |
              npm run "build Prod"
            displayName: 'npm build'
            workingDirectory: "smprod/"
  - stage: Staging
    displayName: Staging-Stage
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy-Staging
        environment: 'smprod-Staging'
        pool:
          name: $(poolName)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
                  displayName: 'Copy frontend build to staging target directory'
                  inputs:
                    sshEndpoint: 'smprod-prod'
                    sourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/smprod/dist/prod'
                    contents: '**'
                    targetFolder: '/smprod/staging/'
                    readyTimeout: '20000'
                    cleanTargetFolder: false
                    overwrite: true
  - stage: Prod
    displayName: Prod-Stage
    dependsOn: Staging
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy-Prod
        environment: 'smprod-Prod'
        pool:
          name: $(poolName)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
                  displayName: 'Copy frontend build to prod target directory'
                  inputs:
                    sshEndpoint: 'smprod-prod'
                    sourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/smprod/dist/prod'
                    contents: '**'
                    targetFolder: '/smprod/prod/'
                    readyTimeout: '20000'
                    cleanTargetFolder: false
                    overwrite: true
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [Publish Artifact Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops)?

Comment: @JSONDerulo yes this would be an idea... but the question is somehow if it is really necessary to make this additional step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with JSONDerulo.Add a Publish Artifacts task is a good choice.

Based on yout YAML sample, the Staging step is running on the Self-hosted agent and saving the artifacts to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.

Your example is indeed a confusing situation（e.g. the next pipeline run is triggered before the last was finished.

Since you are running the same Pipeline and same agent to copy the file, work area is shared between pipeline runs.  In this case, the artifacts generated by the latest build will overwrite the old artifacts.

This will cause confusion.

To alleviate this issue, I suggest that you can add Publish Artifacts task.

Then each build will correspond to the corresponding artifacts.

You can use Download artifacts task to download the target [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops).

The other method is that you need to label the target folder so that it will not be overwritten.

For example: `/smprod/staging-$(build.buildid)/` **(buildid is unique)**

```
                - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
                  displayName: 'Copy frontend build to staging target directory'
                  inputs:
                    sshEndpoint: 'smprod-prod'
                    sourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/smprod/dist/prod'
                    contents: '**'
                    targetFolder: '/smprod/staging-$(build.buildid)/'
                    readyTimeout: '20000'
                    cleanTargetFolder: false
                    overwrite: true
```

Comment: Deployment job doesn't need download artifact as it automatically download all available artifacts. Aslo download build artifact is depracated. So if you decide please use this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops